# Evento y dialog sobre un listview

Tags: android

tengo un listview con elementos, bien, al hacer click sobre uno de ellos me debe aparecer un dialog o similares que dé dos opciones de la forma que sea y diga Acepto o No acepto y que desde el código pueda saber cuál se ha elegido. ¿Cómo puedo afrontar esto? ¿Qué evento debo modificar y como añado el dialog?

Comment: Y que has intentado con respecto a ello colega?

Comment: @Red como lo has realizado en otras preguntas es importante agregar el código que hayas tratado porque por políticas del sitio, pueden cerrar tu pregunta =( , saludos!

Comment: ¿Te ha servido la respuesta de @Elenasys? De ser así, colocarla como aceptada @Red

Comment: Ok, ya lo he hecho, se me había pasado tu mensaje. Como siempre gracias por la ayuda aportada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega un listener, específicamente [**OnItemClickListener**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) a tu ListView, al dar clic en un elemento del ListView, llamarías el dialogo :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
     Log.i("Click", "click en el elemento " + position + " de mi ListView");
     muestraDialogo();

  }
});
```

El método a llamar sería el que cree el dialogo de confirmación:

```
private void muestraDialogo(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Deseas realizar alguna acción?")
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // Aquí lo que deseas realizar
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
           }
       });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Aquí puedes ver la documentación de como crear un dialogo mediante **[Dialog.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("¿Quieres continuar?")
   .setCancelable(false)
   .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // tu código
       }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
       }
   });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```